# Inject imgui in non OpenGL android application

Tags: android, kotlin, imgui

I'm trying to create a mod menu for an android application that's not a game. How can I proceed?

I have an EntryPoint that has Xposed like API and it gets loaded by the target app main activity. Following [imgui's android example](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/tree/master/examples/example_android_opengl3/android) I can get the menu to show up if I create a NativeActivity, but what if I want to overlay it over the target application?